# Computational statistics review

Tags: references, computational-statistics

I'm looking for a mathematically rigorous review of key topics in computational statistics, such as numerical integration, EM algorithms, MCMC, and sampling algorithms. Are there any good lecture notes or short reviews that I could use? I'm currently going through Givens & Hoeting, but it's a massive wall of text and I'm looking for something more concise.

Comment: Charles Geyer has a nice set of notes on MCMC available online.

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonably accessible general introduction to some of these topics, aimed at graduate students, I would recommend:

Evans and Swartz (2000), Approximating Integrals via Monte Carlo and Deterministic Methods, Oxford Statistical Science Series.

https://global.oup.com/academic/product/approximating-integrals-via-monte-carlo-and-deterministic-methods-9780198502784

Answer (score 0):

I'm including a couple of papers I found useful, and will update if I find any others:

[Understanding the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~mmccall/articles/chib_1995.pdf)

[Explaining the Gibbs Sampler](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~mmccall/articles/casella_1992.pdf)

Comment: those two are the papers I used. great recommendation.